# How do fourier processing algorithms deal with "data edges"

Tags: algorithm, signal-processing, fft, theory

I am doing some interesting experiments with audio and image files and Fast-Fourier Transforms (FFTs).

Fast Fourier Transforms are used in signal processing rather than other Fourier Transform algorithms because for large quantities of data they are the only (or one of the only) viable algorithm variants to use, as they scale as O(n log(n)), rather than n^2 as the naive implementation does.

The disadvantage is that the data must be stored in an array which has 2^n elements, for n integer.

When processing some data which does not have 2^n elements, the simple approach is to extend the array to be length 2^n and fill the "empty" elements with zero. (Assuming the mean value of the input signal is zero.)

I wrote a program to process some audio samples taken from WAV files. I tried implementing things such as a low-cut filter. In this case I found that my output signal (after doing the reverse transform) cuts to zero amplitude after a certain period of *time*. This is obviously not what one would expect of a low-pass filter.

I could dump my code at this point, but that is neither useful, nor legal as the source of my algorithm is a text-book with closed source code.

Instead I shall ask the following question.

Is packing out the array with zeros the best possible thing to do? Could this be causing my program to produce the unexpected results I am seeing? if I understand fourier mathematics correctly, having a bunch of zeros at the end of my array will introduce a large amount of low and high-frequency content as this essentially looks like a step-function (low frequency square wave). Should I be doing something else such as implementing my band-pass filter in a different way, for example, splitting the data into smaller groups of say 1024 samples and applying the FT, filter and IFT (inverse FT) to those small groups?

This question has been tagged with theory as it is not related to any specific programming language. (I assume that is the correct tag to use?)

*Edit: It's now working beautifully, thanks all, I was able to pinpoint the 2 mistakes I made using the information below.*

Comment: Many FFT libraries support mixed radix sizes other than just 2^n, but zero padding is fine.

Answer (score 2):

All finite length DFTs and FFT multiply longer data (longer source data or wav file than the FFT) with a rectangular window, which convolves the spectrum with a (periodic) Sinc function.  Zero padding uses a shorter rectangular window, which results in the convolution of the spectrum with a wider Sinc function.

Filtering by multiplication of FFTs results in circular convolution, which wraps the impulse response of the filter around the FFT/IFFT result (e.g. the end of your filtered signal will interfere with the beginning of the filtered signal within the IFFT result).  So you want to zero-pad your data before the FFT, and then see the impulse response of your filter go to zero at or before the very end of the filtered result (e.g. not wrap around).  Look up the overlap-add and overlap-save algorithms, for using short FFTs for fast convolution filtering of longer signals, which take care of the filter impulse response extending into the zero-padded portion.

You can also use FFTs that are not a power of 2 in length.  Any length that can be factored into small primes will work with most modern FFT libraries.

Comment: See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overlap%E2%80%93save_method and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overlap%E2%80%93add_method

Comment: Therefore should I de-convolve my output data? Could this be the cause of the effects I am seeing? (My gut feeling is the answer is "no".)

Comment: You should overlap add or overlap save.  If you filter, you are already convolving , and don't want to undo.

Comment: Can you explain to me what the advantage of overlap add/save is over FFT-ing the whole lot? Does it produce a "more correct output" or is it more efficient, or something else, perhaps?

Comment: @user3728501 overlap-add/overlap-save is a lot faster, and should give you the exact same result as one-shot FFT-based convolution *or* time-domain convolution (sloooow). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overlap%E2%80%93add_method#Cost_of_the_overlap-add_method see the contour plot there.

Comment: @AhmedFasih Thanks for the info - I guess something else must be wrong with my implementation then

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you are interested in.

If you are just interested in spectrum magnitude, then place the real data in the middle of the window to be processed. Just know that this time shift will put a phase shift into the spectrum result.

Regardless of the number of points, do not forget to place a window on your data.  Wikipedia has a good write up on the windowing functions at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function.

If you do not perform some sort of windowing on your real world data, the padded signal will appear to have a step up and a step down at the end of the valid data (which puts a lot of noise into your spectrum giving you the false impression that you have a noise floor).

So, my recommendation, if you primarily care about magnitude:
- develop a hamming window for the number of points of valid data you have.
- apply the hamming window to the data you have

After that you have OPTIONS:

A) if your samples are slightly above a base two number, use the lower base two number (i.e. if you have 1400 points, do two 1024 point FFTs with overlap).  The results of these two FFTs can be "smartly" combined for an aggregate spectrum.  Depending on your fidelity needs, you can do this with more FFTs with a larger portion of overlapped data.  Try to keep the overlap less that 10% to account for your window edges that will get attenuated by the start and end of the windowing functions.

B) place your windowed data anywhere in the FFT input vector (beginning, middle or end, it should only impact your phase results - which is why I asked if phase is important).

If it turns out phase is important, start your valid windowed data at the beginning of the FFT vector.

Regarding your spectrum observations (I just went through the same thing two weeks ago).  If you are looking at a wave file converted from a lossy compression, you are going to be starting with a band limited signal, so expect the spectrum to do an abrupt drop.  My first lossless wave file plot had a huge bald spot from Fs/10 -> 9Fs/10 (which is expected).  For your plots - also display your data in logarithmic bins (linear bins will give you misleading info and squish the lower frequency elements which are the bulk of the signal in compressed music files).

FYI - I recommended hamming (because I did the same thing). A decoded compressed audio signal will only use a portion of your spectrum (decoding a 320kbps stream is sampled at 10Khz), even when decoded to 44.1Khz representation, all of the interesting data should be below 5Khz.

Best of luck

J.R.

P.S. this is my first post here, chime back if you want some pretty pictures from TeraPlot.

Comment: Sure pictures sounds fun - interesting info here, have an up-vote

Answer (score 0):

This is a question for http://dsp.stackexchange.com but yes, zero-padding is perfectly legitimate here.

Here’s why the filtered signal (once it’s back in the time-domain) goes to zero after some time: imagine linearly-convolving the zero-padded signal with your low-pass filter’s impulse response (using the slow O(N^2) time-domain filter implementation). The output will go to zero after the original signal is done, when the filter is just being fed with zeros, right? That result will be the same as the output of FFT-based fast convolution. It’s perfectly normal. Just crop the output signal to the same length of the input and move on with your life.

Caveat on FFT orders: just because power-of-two FFT lengths are “the fastest” in terms of operation count, while FFTs of lengths with low prime factors (3, 5, 7) have slightly higher operation counts, you may find that zero-padding to a low-prime-factor is faster in terms of real-world runtime because of memory costs. A pathological example: if you have a 1025-long signal, you probably don’t want to zero-pad to 2048 and eat the cost of allocating a nearly 2x memory buffer, and running a nearly 2x longer FFT. You’d try 1080-length FFT or something (`1080 = 2^3 * 3^3 * 5`: [`nextprod`](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/stdlib/math/#Base.nextprod) is your friend) and wouldn’t be surprised if it completed much faster than power-of-two.

Comment: "Just crop the output signal to the same length of the input and move on with your life." - I'm confused by this - Imagine I'm processing an audio file - the output signal goes to zero half way through the audio file, not at the beginning or the end, so I can't crop "a beginning or an end off"

Comment: If the output of your FFT/IFFT filter goes to all zeros before the input does, then you likely have some other serious bug in your code unrelated to the FFT length choice or the zero-padding.

Comment: If it's exactly half-way through, it may be a problem with FFTSHIFT. Can you try writing your filter in something like Julia or Python/Numpy so you can see what the "right" answer is and then implement it in your language of choice, once you understand the concepts better?

Comment: Also consider plotting your input signal (WAV file amplitudes) and the output, and showing it. Again, a very dsp.stackexchange.com question.